# How to delete Sqlite android Dd?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am using method `context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);`

Please tell me clearly when should this method be applied in code line !!

```
DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{

    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}
```

Comment: DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
        }

Comment: edit your question and insert your code there instead of comment

Comment: *Why* do you want to delete your database?

Comment: I my application using this concepts once you logout delete over all db i'm fully use for local sqlite db ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your `Context` and you know the name of the database, then you have to use:

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```

When this line gets run, the database should be deleted.

Comment: DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
        {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);

        }

Comment: please tell me why you want to delete db name ,you can also delete db name  using  sqlite (using query)

Comment: I my application using this concepts once  you logout  delete over all db i'm fully use for local sqlite db ....not only delete db name its all db..